# Nested blocks of the same control structure with Alternative Syntax

Tags: php, syntax

Nested blocks of the same control structure with Alternative Syntax in PHP?

following snippet generates

```
syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH)
```

for the last line.

```
        <?php foreach($search_results as $book): ?> 
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $book['title']?></td>
            <td>
                <?php foreach($book["authors"] as $author)?>
                    <?php echo $author . ', '; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I had the same problem with nested `if` structures but don't have any problem with nested blocks that aren't the same.

Comment: You're missing the `:` after the second `foreach()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you forgot `:` in second foreach statement

```
<?php foreach($book["authors"] as $author): ?>
                                          ^
```